# get innerText from Object

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am adding object in shopping cart.

item contains key/value as
 {
[image]

I want to add title with its innerText rather with p and style (Title: de product1).

```js
AddToCart(item) {       
    let checkOutObj = {
        "ID": item["ID"],            
        "CultureDatas": [{
            "Title": item["Title"]["changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity"]
         }]
    };
    this.ShoppingCard.push(checkOutObj);       
}
```

Googled but got only getElementById option which here I cant use.

Any Idea would be great. Thank you

Comment: your code doesn't really make sense, and the question looks a bit unfocused, what is it you actually want, and what does the tag [tag:c#] has to do with your question? What have you tried?

Comment: If you think c# is not fit here, i have removed it. I am trying to get innerText either in checkoutobj or in c# getCheckout object. I am planning to give simple description in the invoice which i am generating using skiasharp in C#

Comment: Hi @SJN Could you please put your edited question here. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your title is stored as HTML. You could manipulate it inside your AddToCart function but be aware it will be string manipulation (use a regex .replace to strip the outer p tags). HTML accessors like innerHTML only work for html that's already present in the DOM. You'll need to insert your stripped HTML from your p into another DOM element so it will render correctly in the webpage.

Comment: Yes, its within p-editor tag, which holds style and html tags. For example